# Why are certain drugs prescribed more often to either males or females?

Tags: medications, gender-specific

I have some original data on prescription frequencies of certain common drugs and I have calculated the gender ratio of patients for each. The list below contains Top 15 of the most commonly prescribed drugs in a major Western country.

[image: drug table]

I am more of a data analyst than a medic, so the reasons for this are not obvious to me. I have used Google/Wikipedia to find the main reason for the prescription of each drug, but my list is by no means exhaustive and I understand it some cases it can be quite nuanced. Could someone with a medical background shed some more light?

My broad generalisations are that men appear to be more often prescribed blood pressure and cholesterol lowering drugs (with a couple of exceptions).

An asthma treatment and an antidepressant are more often prescribed to women. And obviously a thyroid hormone supplement, which is used during pregnancy, is also prescribed much more to women.

Of the two commonest over-the-counter drugs, why is aspirin is prescribed more often to men and paracetamol to women?

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE, Mihael! Some sentences are indeed indication for a very broad question. Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. What has your research shown you so far? Where have you already searched? Please help us to help you. You may improve your question to comply with site guidelines with an [edit] and the help of [ask]. That said, this is not a bad question, just an improvable one. If you could amplify that the specifics are just examples and not your laundry list of possible reasons for individual medications, focusing on  back on your original question? Thanks!

Comment: Hypothiroidism is much more common in women, so levothyroxine is more often prescribed to them. I don't get why 0.20 for males, if it says "during pregnancy." Depression is also more common in women, so more antidepressants for them. Aspirin in low doses is often prescribed as a preventative measure against heart attack and stroke, which are both more common in men.

Comment: @Jan the 0.20 means 20% of patients who got levothyroxine were males (so 80% were women), so what you said makes sense. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: @Jan Women suffer more strokes per year than men and have a higher CHADS score just for being female.

Comment: Between 1950 and 2004: "Overall, the global age-adjusted male/female (m/f) incidence ratio was 1.33 for that period" Sex Difference in Stroke https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3519418/

Comment: To me, the title seemed like the question was about the dosage of drugs, not how many times something was prescribed. Hence the edit. // As it stands now, the answer can't get any more precise than **Because women are more susceptible to some diseases, while men are more susceptible to other diseases**. Maybe pick on (stroke as an example) and have a thorough answer regarding that?

Comment: @Mihael, can you link to the source where you've got the table from?

Comment: I think this is too broad. Sometimes it's because a particular disease is more common in one gender. Other times, it's because there are multiple drugs that could be used, and one has worse side effects in one gender, or is not safe while pregnant or breastfeeding. And other times there is a gender difference in whether doctors think something needs to be treated (how much disruption in the person's life needs to be fixed) or their standards for behaviour - eg tell the women to lose weight, give the men metformin. Pick a drug and you might be able to get an answer.